# Tap gesture only responds to last view

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm adding several views in the code below:

```
    for var i=0;i<sets.count;i++ {
        setView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,y,400,65))
        x=20

        for var c=0;c<sets[i].count;c++ {
            imageView=UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(x,0,60,60))
            dieFaces=types[sets[i][c]] as! NSArray
            file="\(dieFaces![0]).png"
            print(file)
            imageView!.image=UIImage(named: file)
            setView!.addSubview(imageView!)
            x+=60
        }
        setView!.tag=i
        setView!.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        scrollView.addSubview(setView!)
        y+=66
    }
```

Only the last view added is responding to the tap.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tap `UITapGestureRecognizer` can only be attached to a single view, so only the last view is responding. 
You'll need to create a new gesture recognizer for each setView you're attaching it to.

Comment: This did the trick: setView!.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`UIGestureRecognizer` can be added to only one view. So when you add it to another one it just removes itself from the previous view.

I can suggest two options:

1. Add recognizer to a superview. In this case it's `UIScrollView`
2. Or create more recognizers(one per view) and use the same target and action.